# PGFPlots - shift marks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm plotting two lines, more or less on top of each other. This is fine when you can see the colors, but not on a black and white print.

I have added marks, but due to the data points being take with the same interval the marks are also on top of each other. 
Is there a way to shift the markers of each added plot, so they are NOT on top on each other.

Comment: If you get the data from i.e. Matlab, one way to do this is to use something ala

``plot(x(1:3:end),f(x(1:3:end)),'bx',x(1:5:end),f2(x(1:5:end)),'ro')``

where i.e. ``x = -pi:0.01:pi; f = @(x)sin(x); f2 = @(x)sin(x);``

So if you store the data in the same manner it should be a quite easy fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function, I found out, is called `mark phase = x`. It shifts the mark x data points. Must be used together with `mark repeat={y}`, else you will just shift the markers onto another mark.